# Balancing availability and privacy for family stories?

Tags: publishing, privacy, communication

I would like to interview relatives about their lives and stories, and those of their ancestors and descendants, and I'd like to share these stories, but I want to strike a balance between what is available and what is private.

This is the same sort of balance wherein online family trees typically only share information about deceased persons, or in which census data, which is private, becomes public 4 generations later (in several countries).

How do I do this?

To be clear, I'm not asking how to do interviews, and I'm not asking how to share the stories, although that has its own complications.

Is it reasonable to say this?

> Tell me your stories; I will share them with family, and after you
>   pass away, I'll make them available to everyone.

And if so, what of stories of deceased ancestors?

It'd be nice to put things like that on FamilySearch or on Youtube, available to everyone who is interested, now.

What about stories of grandchildren? Should I wait for the grandchild to die?

Lastly, I assume I should obtain some sort of permission slip, either a form, or perhaps a recorded statement.

I can't be the only one who desires to do this, and to balance the needs of privacy now with availability later.

What techniques would you recommend to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I keep two online trees, a public version that strips all of that type of information, and a private one that includes everything.  To access the private tree, users (family members) must login and be authorized.  I find this eliminates a lot of the worries.